# Constraints on parametre satsifying a inequality

Tags: inequality

Suppose, we have $x^2+x+c<0$, what should be the range of values of c so that the given inequation has atleast one negative solution?

if we consider $f(x)= x^2+x+c$, the graph is a parabola opening upward, for the given inequation to have atleast one negative solution $f(x)$ must have atleast one negative solution, and both the roots should be distinct.

Or, discriminant  must be positive,

Solving we get $c>-1/4$

But this bound only gurantees that the $f(x)$ has real and distinct solutions, how can we add the constraint of negative roots?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the relationship between the roots of the quadratic and its coefficients:

$(x - \alpha)(x - \beta) = x^2 - (\alpha + \beta) x + \alpha \beta$

But in this case $-(\alpha + \beta) = 1$ and $\alpha \beta = c$, since you're given the coefficients.

If we arbitrarily choose $\alpha \leq \beta$, then it should be sufficient that $\alpha < 0$, and you can use that to put a bound on $c$ which you can combine with the one you already found.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you please elaborate how can we use $\alpha<0$ condition to  put the bound?  Do we make cases when $\beta$>0,$\beta$<0?

Comment: You can already find $\beta$ in terms of $\alpha$, and multiplying those together gives you an inequality for $c$ as long as you're careful with the signs of the various components.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What is the range of $ f: ( - \infty , 0 ) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = x^2 + x $?

Comment: Thanks, I got it, using that $c <1/4$, but is it a self sufficient bound? Do we still need to apply the discriminant  inequality  ?

Comment: @green_32 By finding the range, we're guaranteeing that there is a solution in the corresponding domain.